# google translate not showing up when https is used in url

Tags: ssl, https, google-translate

For some reason when you go to the url https://www.improvementskills.org/index.cfm  google translate does not show up, but when  you go to http://www.improvementskills.org/index.cfm it works fine.  So I know the issue is with SSL and having https.  Does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading Google's JavaScript with an `http` URL, even when your page is served with `https`.  The browser rejects that, because it's insecure to include non-`https` content in an `https` page.

You need to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/...
```

rather than specifying the URL as `http://translate.google.com/...`  By starting the URL at the double-slash, the browser will use whichever of `http` or `https` the page itself is using.

Comment: @jakefunchion: You should get into the habit of checking the browser console when something weird happens - you'd have seen the error reported there.